# Body class for controller in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

Currently I have this in my layout:

```
<body class="<%= controller.controller_name %>">
```

I want to add an additional class that will be the same for all actions in any controller where it's set, something like:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

body_class 'page'

...

end


class AnotherController < ApplicationController

body_class 'page'

...

end
```

Which will result in:

```
<body class="some page">

<body class="another page">
```

What would be the easiest way to achieve this? Can I use controller class variables for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My solution:

Controller:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  before_filter lambda { @body_class = 'page' }

...

end
```

Layout:

```
<body class="<%= "#{controller.controller_name} #{@body_class}".strip %>">
```

Answer (score 14):

Stop! Stop!
Use this pattern:

```
<body data-controller="#{controller.controller_path}" data-action="#{controller.action_name}">
```

Neat! ha?

And then in your document.ready fire whichever JS script you want for that controller-action combination... ( This can be auto-executed on document ready )

All credit goes to: http://viget.com/inspire/extending-paul-irishs-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution

and:

http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2012/02/a-simple-pattern-to-namespace-and-selectively-execute-certain-bits-of-javascript-depending-on-which-rails-controller-and-action-are-active/

Comment: You forgot to escape the ruby code: ```<body data-controller="<%= controller.controller_path %>" data-action="<%= controller.action_name %>">```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is a layout for that controller. The second thing that comes to mind is a helper that checks the url and applies returns appropriate HTML.

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
layout "new_layout"
 #...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I used @vincent 's way. Since I'm using Rails 5.2.0, `before_filter` is deprecated and has been replaced with `before_action`. I made a little change.

controller:

```rb
class SomeController < ApplicationController
    before_action do 
        @body_class = 'page'
    end

    ...

end
```

layout:

```
<body class="<%= "#{controller.controller_name} #{@body_class}".strip %>">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<body role="document" class="<%= controller.controller_path %> <%= controller.action_name %>" data-controller="<%= controller.controller_path %>" data-action="<%= controller.action_name %>
```

Comment: Please do not code dump. Provide an explanation of what it is you have done.